# Fabric - take the instance ip address

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, fabric

I'm running a few instances on EC2 and need to save their IP address in a database. To save the host names I was using the following function (give in pseudo-code)

```
@roles("servers")
@parallel
def getHosts(instances):
    saveInDB(env.host)
```

However, I need also a similar way to access the public IP of an instance. How can I do this using fabric?

Comment: Are you already using `boto`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Amazon API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) to get the IP or use a command that asks a public service:

```
def test():
    run('curl -s http://whatismijnip.nl')
```

Answer (score 0):

instance's ip addresses could be retrieved via instance metadata api: http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4

ref: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#using-instance-addressing-common

of course you could use boto sdk